# Spring Chained Transaction Manager versus Atomikos

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jta, atomikos

Hi I have a distributed transactions and I have to manage them somehow

Also in spring ecosystem ChainedTransactionManager can do that on the other hand in spring document Atomikos can be used for distributed transactions

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html

Which one I should use?I prefer to stay in spring librarys but Atomikos is much more than spring transaction manager?If someone use them both,Can compare pros and cons

Answer (score 2):

Using Atomikos is a better overall solution. The ChainedTransactionManager is something you can use in some cases. The assumption it makes are stated in the javadocs:

> PlatformTransactionManager implementation that orchestrates transaction creation, commits and rollbacks to a list of delegates. Using this implementation assumes that errors causing a transaction rollback will usually happen before the transaction completion or during the commit of the most inner PlatformTransactionManager.
>
> The configured instances will start transactions in the order given and commit/rollback in reverse order, which means the PlatformTransactionManager most likely to break the transaction should be the last in the list configured. A PlatformTransactionManager throwing an exception during commit will automatically cause the remaining transaction managers to roll back instead of committing.

The chance of committing one transaction and the other one failing still remains with ChainedTransactionManager.

Using Atomikos is a real distributed transaction *all or nothing* on both databases. But this also has some consequences that can affect the support of the application, for example when the TX is fully commited on one DB and prepared on the other, and at that point the application crashes. You'll need to ensure that your application can recover from this scenario. Usually the TX would be fully commited on the second DB when the app is restarted, but that might not happen.

So which one is the right one? It depends.