# Based on which parameters should I choose ChainedTransactionManager versus XA implementation such as Atomikos?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, distributed-transactions, xa

I have a scenario wherein:

1. There are two data bases involved namely `dataSourceOne` and `dataSourceTwo`
2. Some data is saved in `dataSourceOne` and rest is in `dataSourceTwo`
3. If anything fails while saving data to `dataSourceOne` we should rollback
4. If anything fails while saving data to `dataSourceTwo` we should rollback.

I understand that I should be looking for a Distributed Transaction implementation to deal with above mentioned scenario. I have come across two choices 1. [ChainedTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.html) and 2. Two Phase Commit using XA. For #2 choice Atomikos can be an implementation choice.

But I can not understand based on which parameters should I make the choice between two.
I have even gone through an [article](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077963/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) for the same. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412326/spring-chained-transaction-manager-versus-atomikos) one too does not have much details

It would be of great help if you can guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the docs for chained - it’s not a two phase commit and if the inner most tax succeeds then it is not rolled back (and cannot be as it’s been committed by the time the next in the chain is tried).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I understood that the data source with higher chance of failure should be chained at last as rollback happens exactly in a reverse order of the sequence in which transactions are chained. Do you mean to say that when inner most succeeds and outer most fails still transaction is not rolled back?

Comment: Yes. That it what chained means. It’s not XA so it has no means of rolling back a successfully committed tx. “_ChainedTransactionManager should be only used if the application can tolerate or recover from inconsistent state caused by partially committed transactions._” - i.e. partially committed state is your application’s problem to deal with. The docs are clear on this - where does your confusion stem from?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I always assumed that there will never be partial commit state because of ChainedTransactionManager as that is what it is meant to avoid. Or may be there are some specific scenarios in which ChainedTransactionManager can not handle but XA can. I am actually looking for such scenario with an example if possible. Something on the lines for example how Transaction Propagation Required and New differ as shown here: https://www.netsurfingzone.com/spring/transactional-required-vs-requires_new-example-in-spring-boot/

Comment: ChainedTransactionManager doesn’t handle anything. It just chains transaction managers. If your inner manger is the “important one” then this is fine.