Atomikos library has incompatibility packages (from javax.transaction to jakarta.transaction)
I have Atomikos (6.0.0) in Spring Boot 3 and using Java 21. It's working but using a @Deprecated class, "ChainedTransactionManager(transactionManagerOne, transactionManagerTwo)". This way shows me a lot of warnings that I don't like and I want to use the recommended way.
This are the libraries i'm using in my pom.xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

Looking everywhere, tells me to use this:
@Bean
public UserTransaction userTransaction() {
   //uses javax.transaction.*
    return new UserTransactionImp();
}

@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
   //uses javax.transaction.*
    return new UserTransactionManager(); 
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
    //using jakarta.transaction.*
    return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction(), transactionManager());
}

But my problem is that the object JtaTransactionManager is from the new spring-tx-6.1.6 which uses jakarta.transaction.UserTransaction and jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager objects, but the objects new UserTransactionImp() and new UserTransactionManager() are using the old way, with javax.transaction.UserTransaction and javax.transaction.TransactionManager used in the JAR transaction-jta-6.0.0.
How can I make new UserTransactionImp() and new UserTransactionManager() compatible with jakarta.transaction.*?

Please show your dependency declarations.

How are you importing Atomikos in your project? Using the starter:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
  <artifactId>transactions-spring-boot3-starter</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>

I notice that transaction-jdbc, transaction-jms and transaction-jta are automatically imported with jakarta as classifier, thus having transaction-jdbc-6.0.0-jakarta.jar and so on in classpath.
Looking in the repository directory (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/atomikos/transactions-jta/6.0.0/) in fact there are two different jars.
Check if you are importing the "no-jakarta" modules, and in this case try to use the starter, or specify the classifier in pom.xml, like this:
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
  <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
  <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>

Please see also this other question / answer: Failed to convert atomikos J2eeTransactionManager to required type jakarta TransactionManager

Thank you, it looks it should work with classifier). I've a new error because maybe one database doesn't allow XA (i've the error "Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_init_ex'") One database is old, but it compiled. What i don't understand is how ChainedTransactionManager worked whitout XA configured in the DB

I'm not really into this, but it seems that the ChainedTransactionManager does not really use the XA mode of the jdbc driver, while Atomikos does. Also, try read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412326/spring-chained-transaction-manager-versus-atomikos

I suppose ChainedTransactionManager doesn't use XA too. In my company previous tries with distributed transactions were bad! and ChainedTransactionManager writes lots of strange WARNS in the log... so i'll try to use Atomikos XA or separated transactions. Anyway the problem was solved with the 
